# Custom template with validation

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a class

```
export class Credentials {

    constructor() { }

    public username: string;
    public password: string;
}
```

And use it in my component like this

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registerModel: Credentials

  constructor() {
    this.registerModel= new Credentials ()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
  }
}
```

I want to add custom validation to the model before calling my api,
I know this is possible

```
registerModel: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerModel = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
```

but i want to have set classes/interfaces for my models, and inside there have my validation, is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to add a validator is when you define a formControl -or using setValidator-. So, your class can be a property form

```
export class Credentials {
    public form:FormGroup
    public username: string;
    public password: string;

    constructor(data:any=null) { 
      data=data || {username:null,password:null}
      this.username=data.username
      this.password=data.password
      this.form=new FormGroup({
          userName:new FormControl(this.username,Validators.required),
          password:new FormControl(this.password,Validators.required)
      })
    }
}

//and use
this.form=this.credentials.form
```

Or has a property validators

```
export class Credentials {
    public validators:any
    public username: string;
    public password: string;
    constructor(data:any=null) { 
      data=data || {username:null,password:null}
      validators={
         userName:[Validators.required],
         password:[Validators.required]
      }
    }
}

// and use as

this.form = new FormGroup({
  userName: new FormControl(
    this.credentials.username,this.credentials.validators.username
  ),
  password: new FormControl(
    this.credentials.password,this.credentials.validators.password
  )
});
```